# Opening a specific port on Mac

Tags: macos, firewall, port

I need to open a specific port on my mac client (because when I try to connect from server it says "target machine actively refused it ").My problem though is I cannot find a way to add a specific port on my latest Mac OS.

> I go to system pref->securtiy &privacy->firewall-> turn it on (FWIW
>   connection didnt work when I had turned it off)->Firewall options->"+"

This gives me an option to add some application ***but  not a port*** .Can someone point me to the right place to add the port?

Comment: Is there a program listening for connections on that port?  If not, it's closed pretty much by definition.

Comment: That is what my question was ..I dont think it is and that is why I wanted to open it ..not sure how to do it though.